# UIMapKit change bubble color

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I was wondering if there's an easy way to change the color of the annotation's bubbles in a map.

I know you can subclass MKAnnotationView, but it seems a lot of work just to change the color. Is there another way?

This is what I'm trying to do. This design is missing the pin, though, it has to be like that but with a pin, like when using MKPinAnnotationView. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through its subviews and change the right subviews background color.

```
//change accordingly...
for(UIView *subview in [MKAnnotationView subviews]) {
    //get the right subview and change its background color

}
```

Comment: MKPinAnnotationView, which is the one I'm trying to subclass, doesn't return any subviews.